# How to reference a local resource dictionary from within the same FrameworkElement's property in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, resourcedictionary

Is there a way to reference a local `ResourceDictionary` from within the same `FrameworkElement`'s property?

I tried the following

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource txt}">
    <TextBlock.Resources>
        <x:String x:Key="txt">asdf</x:String>
    </TextBlock.Resources>
</TextBlock>
```

but get the error

> The resource "txt" could not be resolved.

Moving the txt resource from the `TextBlock` to the `Page` resources would work but that seems messy and i was hoping that it's possible to reference a `FrameworkElement`s  local `ResourceDictionary`.

Using `CustomResource` instead of `StaticResource` at least allows to auto complete to *txt*, but it doesn't work because then invoking `Initializecomponent` throws an exception: "*No custom resource loader set*" and i'm not sure if implementing and setting a custom loader would solve that at all.

Is there a way to do this using the local resource dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

UWP FrameworkElement resource lookup looks for parent control resources, not child control resources.

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-resource-dictionary#every-frameworkelement-can-have-a-resourcedictionary) details how `Resources` works.

## Edit

It is recommended to use Resource Dictionary file.

1. Right click on your project
2. Choose Add
3. Choose Resource Dictionary.

You can put your all your resource in this file.

Then add a resource file reference in App.xaml.

**Dictionary1.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

   <Style x:Key="txt" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="asdf"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Page.xaml**

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource txt}" ></TextBlock>
```

Comment: Is there any chance this can be changed by using a `CustomResource` or something else to include lookup on self (neither parent nor child)?

Comment: The xaml resouces needs to be defined before it is used. It means you need to define the `txt` string before the the TextBlock starts to look put for this resource.
Could you please tell me why you want to add and use the resource like that?

Comment: This is for a visual prototype which is very messy (all in one page) and where i hoped to avoid crowding the page resources so that there's at least some locality.

Comment: @ridilculous. You can refer to my edit, it is recommended to use Resource Dictionary file.

Comment: @ridilculous Have you checked my update?

Comment: I have but couldn't write something up and my life's a lil too busy for sad reasons atm. Will come back here later.